# How can I find the last non-empty column number of an Excel file using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How can I find the last non-empty column number of an Excel file using openpyxl?

So if the last column with data is column N, how do I get that letter and then convert it to a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want Worksheet.max_column, which is a number.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['N3'] = 4
ws.max_column # returns 14
```

You can convert the column letter using:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
column_index_from_string('N') # => 14
get_column_letter(14) # => N
```